# Почему на странице текст на русском отображается в виде каких-то иероглифов?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_BB.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum" 
rel="stylesheet">
  <title>BB Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
 <nav class="dws-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Про Фонд</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Project</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Education</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Career</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Education online</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а где закрывающий тег header?

Comment: Могли бы мы все увидеть содержимое style_BB.css ? Есть мысль, что шрифт, который подключен и используется вами, сделан или подключен так себе.

Comment: body{
  background-image: url("images/BBF_logo.png");
}
header{
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: Cuprum, Arial, Helvetical, sans-serif;
}

Comment: странно. Сейчас попробовал у себя. Все норм. Скорее всего дело действительно в кодировке, как вам и сказал @Qwertiy. Попробуйте создать новый index.html c utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что файл надо сохранять в utf-8.

Comment: так и делал, ничего не поменялось